# Which RAM slots corresponds to CPU 1 on HP ProLiant BL460c G6

Tags: memory, hp-proliant, blade-server

I have this server with 2 CPUs and 12 DIMMs. All slots are occupied. I need to change a faulty memory module. I know it's in the slot 3 (E) of the CPU 1. And here comes my question since I haven't found info in the HP PDF guide.
How do I know which bank (6 slots) of DIMMs belongs to the CPU 1?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most HPs I've worked with have a system board layout diagram on the inside of the lid. Have you checked there?

Comment: Yes I checked but evidently I need glasses :-P as the answer was in the diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the RAM slots adjacent to the CPU1 socket.

[image]